# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

While trying to run my web applicaton, I'm getting the below mentioned error. Previously my application was running fine. But today i gave maven clean and then tried ruuning it by giving maven goal as tomcat:run, I'm getting this error

```
[INFO]

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] 

[INFO] Total time: 6.754s

[INFO] Finished at: Tue Mar 11 15:09:44 IST 2014

[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/28M

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) on project metaDB: Could not start Tomcat: Memory database file 
D:\WORK\target\tomcat\conf\tomcat-users.xml cannot be read -> [Help 1]

[ERROR] 

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
```

please help to over come this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file for Tomcat users in:

```
D:\WORK\target\tomcat\conf\tomcat-users.xml
```

and add the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users>
 <role rolename="tomcat"/>
 <role rolename="admin"/>
 <role rolename="manager"/>
 <user  username="admin" password="admin" roles="tomcat,admin,manager"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Answer (score 8):

Delete the folder "D:\WORK\target\tomcat\" and try again, the tomcat-maven-plugin would re-create this folder and the file "tomcat-users.xml".

Comment: A much better solution than the accepted answer.  It's something I would like the plugin to recreate rather than changing stuff myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use tomcat maven plugin, start the web application
2. Rebuild the project
3. Restart tomcat maven plugin.
4. The error must occur

**Solution:** Before rebuilding the project, you must stop tomcat maven plugin first.